# how to ssh to a VirtualBox machine?

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

I have an existing Virtualbox machine which i created through [veewee](https://github.com/jedi4ever/veewee) called say `precise64`.
I can login via the Virtualbox GUI, i could export the box and use it with [vagrant](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant) to create a new machine called say `chef`. Vagrant also setup ssh and networking on the machine `chef`.

But i cannot setup ssh for the first machine i created `precise64`. I created a new Host-only network and a host only network. The ssh forwording rules were already set. But ssh still does not work. I did not look the source code for veewee but i looked at the source code for Vagrant and it calls `VBoxManage hostonlyif` to create the network but `VBoxManage showvminfo` does not show the ip-address for the machine `chef`.

I a bit lost at this point. A step-by-step tutorial on how to add SSH-login to an existing Virtualbox machine would be helpful ? assuming that more than one machines already esist and they have different IP-addresses

Also can veewee create the hostonly networking like vagrant does when bringing up a new machine ?

related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11951579/adding-vagrant-to-an-existing-virtualbox-machine

Answer (score 1):

What operating system are you using? Linux and Mac's have ssh installed by default. This is used when you run the command:

```
vagrant ssh
```

---

Otherwise if you are on a Windows box, you will need to do a full [Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) install (so you get pageant too) or you will need to install ssh through cygwin for your system.

You can test if ssh is working by running the command 'ssh' in a terminal.

If you see the following you have ssh:

```
usage: ssh [blah blah blah]
```

by default, vagrant fowards port 22 on the vm to port 2222 on the host.

Try the command:

```
ssh -p 2222 vagrant@localhost
```